# Mysql results for joins where some fields are empty

Tags: mysql

I hope someone can help, I've been trawling SO for hours and can't find an answer that does what I need (or at least I can't see how the answers apply to my situation)

So I have 3 tables, Horses, owners, and horse_owners

```
Table: horses
ID    Name    age
1     arkle   3
2     shergar 4
3     daisy   2

Table: owners
ID    Name   
1     Joe
2     Jack
3     Susan
4     Mike

Table: horse_owners
owner_id    horse_id
1           1
2           1
3           1
4           2
```

There are other fields but for the sake of simplicity I've removed them. 
I want to run a query that lists the horses, and their owners (if they have any).

Here's what I have now:

```
SELECT 
  h.id, 
  h.name, 
  h.age 
  GROUP_CONCAT(o.name separator ', ') as owners
FROM 
  horses h
LEFT JOIN 
  horse_owners ho 
ON 
  h.id = ho.horse_id
LEFT JOIN
  owners o
ON
  ho.owner_id = o.id
```

I'm using the group_concat function to combine the owners names where some have multiple owners. But the problem is the query only returns horses that have owners. I want to see all horses whether they have owners or not.

Comment: Your query looks right to me. You're missing a comma after `h.age`, but I assume it got lost during the posting-to-StackOverflow process (since that's a syntax error otherwise), and you're omitting the `GROUP BY` clause, but MySQL generally infers it when needed . . . maybe it's worth adding the explicit `GROUP BY`, just to make sure that the implicit one isn't the problem somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 
  h.id, 
  h.name, 
  h.age,
  coalesce(group_concat(o.name order by o.name separator ', '),'Nobody') as owners
from 
  horses h
left join 
  horse_owners ho 
on 
  h.id = ho.horse_id
left join
  owners o
on
  ho.owner_id = o.id
 group by h.id
```

Comment: That's it. Many thanks. I had tried the coalesce function at one point but it also needed the group by to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  h.id, 
  h.name, 
  h.age, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(o.name separator ', ') as owners
FROM 
  horses h
LEFT JOIN 
  horse_owners ho 
ON (h.id = ho.horse_id)
LEFT JOIN
  owners o
ON (ho.owner_id = o.id)
```